# How can I detect if a user changes their password?

Tags: filters, password

I would like to track when a user changes their password. Is there a way to detect when a password has been changed?

Comment: WordPress already does this.  You'll get an email when the password is changed.

Comment: I have never received an email when another user changed their password.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WordPress sends an email to the admin's email when a user resets their password.

To get a notification when a user changes their password you could hook into the `profile_update` action which is fired when a user's profile is updated.

When the action is fired WordPress has already validated and updated the user's details we only need to check if the user submitted a password with the request, if it was submitted then the user's password has changed.

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) || '' == $_POST['pass1'] ) {
        return;
    }

    // password changed...
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `if` statement be like this: `if ( ! isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) || '' != $_POST['pass1'] ) {`

Comment: @gmaggio , no because the first `if` verifies if the password is changed and if the password isn't null. Both must be false. if the second is `'' != $_POST['pass1']` any password, not empty will return TRUE

Comment: Just a note that if anyone's trying to do this with the Profile Builder / Profile Builder Pro plugins, their password fields have an extra 'w', i.e. `$_POST['passw1']`  Also note you don't need to check if the password is valid / the passwords don't match, because if there's a problem `profile_update` won't run.

Comment: For a more accurate assesment if the users password was changed, you should do a check to make sure that `$_POST['pass1'] === $_POST['pass2']` because if the user had entered the wrong text into one of the inputs, then the page would still be submitted, however their password would not actually change. Most likely they would make another attempt, and this check would prevent false or double notification.