# Hook *after* user password change?

Tags: hooks, password

I know that password_reset hooks:

```
Runs after the user submits a new password during password reset 
but before the new password is actually set.
```

but there is a similar hook *AFTER* the new password is actually set?

EDIT: It would be logical to use profile_update but I tried, and profile_update seems not get called in case of password change for a 'lost password' procedure, for example.
My real problem is auto login after password reset, and the only solution found till now, was using password_reset hook calling manually a wp_set_password before executing my code, so to be sure that password gets changed and THEN my code gets executed. This is not a clean procedure, and I am wondering if there is a solution that is less 'hacky'... I searched a lot, looking at every action hook in wordpress doc, but i can't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wonder if you're looking for [this one](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/user.php#L2086):

```
 /**
  * Fires after the user's password is reset.
  *
  * @since 4.4.0
  *
  * @param object $user     The user.
  * @param string $new_pass New user password.
  */
  do_action( 'after_password_reset', $user, $new_pass );
```

It was introduced in WordPress 4.4 and lives within the `reset_password()` function. The `after_password_reset` hook fires after the `wp_set_password()`.

### Update

Here's an untested pre 4.4 workaround idea:

```
/**
 * Support for the 'after_password_reset' hook in WordPress pre 4.4
 */
add_action( 'password_reset', function( $user, $new_pass )
{
    add_filter( 'pre_option_admin_email', 
        function( $pre_option, $option ) use ( $user, $new_pass )
        {
            // Setup our 'after_password_reset' hook
            if( ! did_action(  'after_password_reset' ) )
                do_action( 'after_password_reset', $user, $new_pass );

            return $pre_option;  
        }  10, 2 );    
}, 10, 2 );
```

where you should now have your own custom `after_password_reset` hook.

Remember to **backup** database before testing.

Comment: Ah!! They noticed that, at the end! Unfortunately, i have 4.3.1 and I am not sure updating is a good idea at this point. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hopefully you can upgrade to the latest version soon, that's always highly recommended. In the meanwhile I updated the answer with an untested idea. @SashaGrievus

Comment: I hope to! Only, i have to wait a bit for it contains a lot of custom code and must be tested. :) Thank you for the idea. I'm going to test it asap!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have to use `profile_update` hook.

There is a similar question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51337/how-can-i-detect-if-a-user-changes-their-password), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641663/execute-a-function-when-password-changed-in-wordpress).

So this post might actually be considered duplicate.

Comment: That is what it would be logical but tried, and profile_update seems not get called in case of password change for a 'lost password' procedure, for example.

Comment: Then I'm not sure. You can see the code for password reset here: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/password_reset?version=4.1&file=wp-includes/user.php

Comment: wow! this is good! I was worried about missing something that would be done after password_reset, and that's it! Thank you very much!