# How to intercept update_option() before it saves data?

Tags: database

I am working with redux framework and need to save theme option values to a file right before it is saved in DB. 
Is there a way to intercept

```
update_option()
```

right before it saves data in DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off using the `update_option_` action instead. This will allow you to write to your file after the option has been updated (as apposed to before). If another plugin hooks into pre_update_option_ and alters the value after your plugin has saved it then you will have saved an incorrect value.

I would use:

```
add_action( 'update_option_myoption', function( $old_value, $new_value ) {
   //Do something with the new value
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Very good point.

Answer (score 4):

There is a filter exactly for that: `pre_update_option_{option_name}`. If the is option is, for example, names `myoption`, you could use somthing like this:

```
add_filter( 'pre_update_option_myoption', function( $new_value, $old_value ) {

   //Do something before returning the new value to be saved in database

   return $new_value;

}, 10, 2);
```

Referene: [pre_update_option_(option_name)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_update_option_(option_name))

It would be useful a general `pre_update_option` for all options, but as far I know such filter doesn't exist.

You asked about someting to use *right before* the option is saved to DB but you may be also interested in `update_option_{option_name}` action. This action is fired *right after* the option has been saved. Please, note that `update_option_{option_name}` is an action while `pre_update_option_{option_name}` is a filter, both are intented for different things. Basically (very basically), actions are intended to perform tasks and don't `return` values; filters `return` values and they are intented to work with or modify data (although there is nothing that stop you to perform tasks in filters).

Answer (score 0):

Lead dev of Redux here. You can use one of our filters to match your needs:

"redux/validate/{$this->args['opt_name']}/defaults" - Only on resetting defaults

"redux/validate/{$this->args['opt_name']}/defaults_section" - Only on resetting one section

"redux/options/{$this->args['opt_name']}/import" - Only on import

"redux/validate/{$this->args['opt_name']}/before_validation" - before validation

"redux/options/{$this->args['opt_name']}/validate" - after validation

Comment: hehehhe,  was just thinking about you dovy , we got to talk talk bud 
https://github.com/reduxframework/kirki/issues/208

Comment: bloating the code with entire framework to do something which is a one liner? just a no-no