# Webservice credential storage

Tags: plugins, security, web-services

I am developing a plugin that calls a web-service with a security header. Can anyone recommend a best practice for storing those credentials on the WordPress site? Right now my best option seems to be storing the username, password, etc as admin options belonging plugin in the db. Other options would require the site admin to edit the plugin code or config file directly. I do not want these credentials traveling with the plugin should it somehow become distributed to other users. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this: [How to store username and password to API in wordpress option DB?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25062/how-to-store-username-and-password-to-api-in-wordpress-option-db)

tl;dr:

- use OAuth, if the web service supports it, or if the web server is run by yoursefl
- Store the data encrypted in the database, using as encryption wordpress installation-wide unique keys, ad you can see in the link.